# Is it possible to access mptcp sysctl inside docker?

Tags: docker, sysctl, mptcp

I would like to access `sysctl -n net.mptcp.mptcp_enabled` from docker container, but currently I couldn't achieve it. I already tried the below things.

1.

```
docker run -d --sysctl net.mptcp.mptcp_enabled=1 --name=test -p 3100:3100 my_container

75dcbdc65a1539ce734a413cb6e23bf216aea76f6533c52280d3e866270424b9
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: write sysctl key net.mptcp.mptcp_enabled: open /proc/sys/net/mptcp/mptcp_enabled: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

2. 

```
docker run -d --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --privileged  --name=test -p 3100:3100 my_container
```

This time container starts but there is no file under /proc/sys/net/mptcp/mptcp_enabled

3.

```
docker run -d -v /proc:/proc --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --privileged  --name=test -p 3100:3100 my_container
```

This is also the same as 2.

I saw that a [sysctl that starts with net.* are namespaced](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#:%7E:text=Sysctls%20beginning%20with%20net.*) but wonder why this is not working.

**Note: My host machine has mptcp supported kernel and I can see all mptcp related files under /proc/sys/net/mptcp/***

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. Using `--net=host` should solve it.

Try this:

```
docker run -d --net=host --name=test -p 3100:3100 my_container
```